# numberOfRowsInSection being called too many times in iOS8?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

It seems that since iOS 8 came out, when displaying an existing UITableView, `numberOfRowsInSection` function always being called.

On iOS 8, when switching tabs from a tab bar controller, and one contains a table view, 
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
 is always called even when no table functions have been called.

On iOS 7, when switching tabs from a tab bar controller, and one contains a table view,
 `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
 is not called.

Anyone know why this behavior is in ios8 ? A fix around it?

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, when switching the tabs tableview calling some of the delegates, i tested with the "Time Profiler" and found that if your viewController has a tableview added on it in ios 8 it automatically calls [UITableView didMoveToWindow] (private methods) in ios 8. And after that the whole shit happens, it calls the table delegates and performance goes down. I am trying to find out how to stop these calls, if anyone find it please update..

Here is the screenshot if the functions call stack, after i switch between tabs -

http://www.imageno.com/77dx9lss0qlmpic.html